# Inserting int in array mid position

Tags: java, arrays, int

The task is to create a 20-element `int` array and fill it with random integers from index 0 to index 18. Then I would like to insert -1 in the middle and print the entire array. There is something wrong with my code, though.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Zadanie5_3{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] tab = new int[20];

        for(int i = 0; i <= 18; i++){
            tab[i] = rand.nextInt();
        }   

        for(int j = 19; j > tab.length/2; j--){
            tab[j] = tab[j--];
            tab[tab.length/2] = -1; 

            System.out.println(tab[j]); 
        }

    }   

}
```

Comment: can you post your output please

Comment: So you want to shift the array to right when inserting -1 in middle element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Zadanie5_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] tab = new int[20];

        for(int i = 0; i <= 18; i++){
            tab[i] = rand.nextInt();
        }   

        for(int j = 19; j >= 9; j--){
            tab[j] = tab[j-1];
        }

        tab[9] = -1;

        // print
        for(int i = 0; i <= 18; i++){
            System.out.println(tab[i]);
        } 
    }   

}

result:

1956305001
-2096126360
98350219
1446603176
1822536231
-585584710
1907161554
-1249344271
330285354
-1
-2035667564
935350135
178577755
1025860367
-965180067
1164224066
1726709678
1615705033
-1258924041
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the second for loop.

`tab[j] = tab[j--];`

The `j--` will reduce the value of j by 1. So in each iteration j will be decreased by 2 instead of 1.

`tab[j] = tab[j - 1];` is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your second for loop into two loops. The first loop shifts the upper halve of the array up by one index. The second loop outputs the complete array.

In the first loop, you place your statement:

```
        tab[j] = tab[j--];
```

However, you have to adjust this statement, since `j--` actually decreases `j`. Replace it with this statement:

```
        tab[j] = tab[j - 1];
```

In between these two loops, you assign the `-1` to the index in the middle. This operation does not belong into a loop, since it only has to be executed once. Also, it should only be executed after the shifting of the other elements is done, because else you override the element that is currently in the middle.